# How to change page title with routing in Angular application?

Tags: angular, angular5

Is there any npm module/ other way like [React-Helmet](https://github.com/nfl/react-helmet) that allows us to change page title as we route through our Angular application?

PS: I am using Angular 5.

Answer (score 247, accepted):

You have a TitleService in Angular 5. Inject it in your component's constructor, and use the `setTitle()` method.

```ts
import {Title} from "@angular/platform-browser";

....

constructor(private titleService:Title) {
  this.titleService.setTitle("Some title");
}
```

Here are the docs from Angular: https://angular.io/guide/set-document-title

Comment: @VishalGulati Yes, it does

Comment: Here is an update to the cookbook by Angular (works in Angular 6) : https://angular.io/guide/set-document-title

Comment: Does this work with nested components that each set their own individual title too?

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, yes, it does.

Comment: If you're just using the titleService in the constructor, you can omit the `private` and the `this` so stop it adding to the component `this` value

Answer (score 46):

In Angular v14, there is a built-in strategy service for collecting the title from the route based on the primary router outlet, and setting the browser's page title.

```js
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { AboutComponent } from './about.component';
import { HomeComponent } from './home.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'home',
    component: HomeComponent,
    title: "'My App - Home' // <-- Page title"
  },
  {
    path: 'about',
    component: AboutComponent,
    title: "'My App - About Me'  // <-- Page title"
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

See [here](https://dev.to/brandontroberts/setting-page-titles-natively-with-the-angular-router-393j)

Comment: not using ng14 but good to know for future purposes - excellent answer

Comment: This should be higher up, this is the best way for simple apps with only a few pages!

Answer (score 36):

Here is tested way to set page title on Angular 8 but you can use it on Angular 5 as well.
Once you set this you have to just set title on route file and all will set automatically.

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute, Router, NavigationEnd } from '@angular/router';
import { Title } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { filter, map } from "rxjs/operators";

@Component({
    selector: 'app-root',
    templateUrl: './app.component.html'
})
export class AppComponent {

    constructor (private router: Router, private activatedRoute:    ActivatedRoute, private titleService: Title) {
        this.router.events.pipe(
            filter(event => event instanceof NavigationEnd),
            map(() => {
                let child = this.activatedRoute.firstChild;
                while (child) {
                    if (child.firstChild) {
                        child = child.firstChild;
                    } else if (child.snapshot.data &&    child.snapshot.data['title']) {
                        return child.snapshot.data['title'];
                    } else {
                        return null;
                    }
                }
                return null;
            })
        ).subscribe( (data: any) => {
            if (data) {
                this.titleService.setTitle(data + ' - Website Name');
            }
        });
    }

}
```

And on route file you can do something like this:

```js
const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: 'dashboard',
        component: DefaultDashboardComponent,
        data: {
            title: 'Dashboard'
        }
    }
];
```

Comment: I use your solution for the navigation. It works if I click on the links in the navigation but when I refresh the window (`F5`), it doesn't display the right title as it should be. Any idea to fix it?

Comment: @Anh-ThiDINH make sure you have all required modules imported on each module files if you are using lazyloading.

Comment: @Ankur how to make this "Website name" as dynamic from a constant file?

Comment: @BillNathan You can skip the route file data for the title and read that constant file on the Component file to set title with `this.titleService.setTitle(your_variable_with_title_string)`

Comment: exactly what I want to do - thanks

Comment: This is why I love SO. Very elegant solution.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a non-recursive solution that also fixes the replication of titles in case of path-less or component-less nested routes.

Make sure to add Angular's `Title` service to your application: https://angular.io/guide/set-document-title.

Then in your `app.component.ts`

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Title } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NavigationEnd, Router } from '@angular/router';
import { filter } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(
    private readonly router: Router,
    private readonly titleService: Title
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.router.events.pipe(
      filter((event) => event instanceof NavigationEnd)
    ).subscribe(() => {
      this.titleService.setTitle(this.getNestedRouteTitles().join(' | '));
    });
  }

  getNestedRouteTitles(): string[] {
    let currentRoute = this.router.routerState.root.firstChild;
    const titles: string[] = [];

    while (currentRoute) {
      if (currentRoute.snapshot.routeConfig.data?.title) {
        titles.push(currentRoute.snapshot.routeConfig.data.title);
      }

      currentRoute = currentRoute.firstChild;
    }

    return titles;
  }

  getLastRouteTitle(): string {
    let currentRoute = this.router.routerState.root.firstChild;

    while (currentRoute.firstChild) {
      currentRoute = currentRoute.firstChild;
    }

    return currentRoute.snapshot.data?.title;
  }
}
```

Accessing the specific `routeConfig.data` prevents the repetition of the inherited `title` attribute.

And in `main-routing.module.ts` or any of your other routing files:

```js
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: MainComponent,
    data: { title: 'MyApplication' },
    children: [
      {
        path: '',
        canActivateChild: [AuthGuard],
        children: [
          {
            path: 'dashboard',
            loadChildren: () => import('../dashboard/dashboard.module').then(m => m.DashboardModule),
            data: { title: 'Dashboard' }
          },
          {
            path: 'settings',
            loadChildren: () => import('../settings/settings.module').then(m => m.SettingsModule),
            data: { title: 'Settings' }
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
];
```

Answer (score 2):

I would prefer to add a wrapper class just to make sure that i will not change everywhere if **import {Title} from "@angular/platform-browser";** changed in the upcoming release :) ... Maybe Something called "AppTitleService"

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Title } from '@angular/platform-browser';

@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class AppTitleService {

    constructor(private titleService: Title) { }

    getTitle() {
        this.titleService.getTitle();
    }
    setTitle(newTitle: string) {
        this.titleService.setTitle(newTitle);
    }
}
```

Comment: has a feel of good practice and modularity +1

Answer (score 1):

```
// Component.ts
```

```js
    
    import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
    import { Router, NavigationEnd, ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
    import { filter } from 'rxjs/operators';
    
    @Component({
      selector: 'app-component',
      templateUrl: './component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./component.css']
    })
    export class Component implements OnInit {
    
      constructor(private router: Router, private route: ActivatedRoute) { }
    
      path: string[] = [];
      pathTitle: string;
    
      ngOnInit() {
        this.router.events.pipe(
          filter(event => event instanceof NavigationEnd)
        ).subscribe((event: NavigationEnd) => {
            this.path = event.url.substring(1).split('/');  //  URL => stackOverflow
            this.pathTitle = this.route.root.firstChild.snapshot.data.title; // data.title => stack Overflow
        });
      }
    
    // app-routing.module.ts
    const routes: Routes = [
      { 
        path: 'stackOverflow', 
        component: Component, 
        data: {title: 'stack Overflow'}
       }
    ];
```

Answer (score -3):

**Today is 2022-10-14**. Answers above including Angular's own doc are very good, but not the easiest/lightest, and sometimes tedious.

We have hundreds of components/pages, Angular 12+, `title` and `<meta name="description" ...>` are typically static, so the best way is hardcode without adding any packages:

```
<head>
  <title...>
  <meta ...>
  ...
</head>
```

While Chrome and Edge, including `META SEO inspector` show all `title` and `meta` from index.html and components, browsers display only the **first** `title` in the order of discovery.

Solution:

1. Move `<title>` and `<meta>` of index.html to bottom
2. Every component/page to have its own else default to index’s

Reasons:

- `<head>` is no longer mandatory in HTML5 whom was released in 2014
- `<title>` and `<meta>` can be placed anywhere
- They are allowed to have multiple entries even for the same duplicated name
- `<title>`, first discovered will be used for display so component/page’s shows
- `<meta>`, all are used.
- See this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33110559/5063031) for details.

With one simple adjustment inside of index.html, Wa-La, all pages display the corresponding title. No need to introduce any new component/package and update hundreds of files, and SEO 100!

BTW, this is not just for Angular, apply to all others including .NET, Vue and React.

Comment: Your solution is great, but for Angular there is better solution

This is what I am using for my Apps:
- I set title and description meta as empty in index.html
- I inject title and meta services in my appObserver service, like the auth service or the main bootstrap service
- I made two functions setTitle() and resetTitle(), and same for description
- In app component I call resetTitle() and resetDesc
- In any component, I inject the appObserver service, and use setTitle() in constructor, and use resetTitle() in ngOnDestroy()

This is the safest way and the best for SEO as Angular App

Comment: @IslamElKassas Your solution is like other above, great. But what's better than static content being static?