# How to change the parent title to the value from the child in Angular?

Tags: angular, parent

I'm looking for solution where I can switch dynamically (depending on the component we are in) value in parent component. Value should be different in each component.

Is the service not too much for this kind of solution? Is there a simpler solution in Angular?

Parent - Some text {{ title }}

Child1 - title = "title one"
Child2 - title = "title two"

etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using [EventEmitter](https://angular.io/api/core/EventEmitter):

**child-component.ts**

```js
import { Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core'; 
title: string;
@Output() titleChange: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();

ngOnInit() {
  this.title = 'child title';
  this.titleChange.emit(this.title);
}
```

**parent-component.html**

```
<p>{{title}}</p>
<app-child (titleChange)="onTitleChange($event)"></app-child>
```

**parent-component.ts**

```js
title: string

onTitleChange(value: string) {
   this.title = value;
}
```

Comment: I used that solution.

But Angular where throwing error every time it switch "panel" so I have to add 

onTitleChange(value: string) {
  setTimeout(()=>{
   this.title = value;
});

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the RoutingModule? If yes, you could add a `data` attribute (i.e. title) in your routing definition and then subscribe to route changes in the parent component.

For example like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58863966/3073719

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not using RoutingModule here. It's more complicated :P