# What causes the failure to change the page title per route, in this Angular app?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have been working an app with Angular 8.

I am currently trying to *set the page title from the router*. For this purpose, in `app.module.ts` I have:

In `app.component.ts`:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
})
export class AppComponent {
  constructor() {}
  public title: String = 'Employees';

  changeTitle(val: String) {
    this.title = val;
  }
}
```

In `app.component.html`:

```
<app-navbar></app-navbar>
<div class="container">
  <h1 class="mt-2 mb-3">{{ title }}</h1>
  <router-outlet (onSetTitle)="changeTitle($event)"></router-outlet>
</div>
```

In `employee-details.component.ts`:

```
import { Component, EventEmitter, OnInit, Output } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { Employee } from '../../models/empModel';
import * as data from '../../data/employees';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-employee-details',
  templateUrl: './employee-details.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./employee-details.component.css'],
})
export class EmployeeDetailsComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(private ActivatedRoute: ActivatedRoute) {}

  @Output() onSetTitle = new EventEmitter<String>();
  public empsArray: Employee[] = data.employees;
  public employee: any = {};

  public setTitle() {
    console.log(this.ActivatedRoute.snapshot.data['title']);
    this.onSetTitle.emit(this.ActivatedRoute.snapshot.data['title']);
  }

  public getEmployee() {
    const empno = Number(this.ActivatedRoute.snapshot.paramMap.get('empno'));
    this.employee = this.empsArray.find((item) => item.empno == empno);
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.setTitle();
    this.getEmployee();
  }
}
```

#### Stackblitz

I have put together a **[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-modal-bootstrap-mfmjwo?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)** too.

#### The problem

The initial value of the `title` variable does not change, after navigating to the `EmployeeDetailsComponent` even though the `setTitle()` method does return the correct value for the `title` variable.

#### Questions

1. What am I doing wrong?
2. What is the most reliable way to fix this issue?

Comment: My suggestion would be to use a service. Routes keep your components decoupled from the rendering hierarchy, don't try to change that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You dont need the output part in `employee-details.component.ts` and in `<router-outlet>` and you can remove that function at all.

And solution to this was receiving the datas that you gave in component declaration and not in the Output() from employee-details.component.ts

[Link to Demo](https://angular-modal-bootstrap-aecr4q.stackblitz.io/)

[Link to stackblitz working version](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-modal-bootstrap-aecr4q?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fcomponents%2Femployee-details%2Femployee-details.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts)

If you find it helpful mark it as answered!

Comment: I don't know what you changed. Can you provide relevant code in the answer, so that I can _understand_ what you did? Thanks!

Comment: The solution to this was receiving the title from datas that you assigned to routes in app.module.ts. In app.component.ts (line 10-16) is the way that we got the datas and assigned it to the variable title and each time we change the route it changes the titles dynamically.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can not add a click event to the router outlet. This is not the proper way.

Here is the solution on StackOverflow.

[How to change page title with routing in Angular application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47900447/how-to-change-page-title-with-routing-in-angular-application)

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion would be to use a service. Routes keep your components decoupled from the rendering hierarchy, don't try to change that

You can create a custom  that allows you to do that or more common, use a shared service to communicate between parent component and routed component. [Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37662456/angular-2-output-from-router-outlet/41989983#41989983)

Answer (score 1):

You should avoid using eventEmitter through router-outlet.

Create a service (TitleService) to share the data between your AppComponent and EmployeeDetailsComponent through an Observable.